# how to make cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js into local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, popper.js

i'm having problem with displaying bootstrap navbar/anything that need JS in my vue 2project, im currently using CDN on this project

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

perhaps there is another way to install and import this into local?

Comment: Are you able to download the file? Then you could use `<script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` (assuming the file is in the same directory as the page)

Comment: omg It worked, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`
i solve this problem by adding this thing into my index.html + downloaded file

Comment: Consider only using JS/CSS from your own website/server. Executing code from a third-party does leave your site open to abuse